# Paperjs Tween not working on property radius

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, paperjs

Tween not working on radius of paperjs Circle, it works on fillColor but not on radius

```
    var path = new Path.Circle({
    radius: 100,
    fillColor: 'blue',
    center: view.center
});

path.tween(
    { radius: 100, fillColor: 'blue' },
    { radius: 200, fillColor : 'red'},
    2000
);
```

JSBin code here : https://jsbin.com/zixarupixe/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `radius` is not really a property of the circle that can be get or set, it is just a constructor argument.
In order to do what you want, you can disable matrix application on the path with `item.applyMatrix = false` and play with its `scaling` property.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/bVDNCsIwDH6V0IsTyqg7Vjx5FgSP6iHrohZrN9rOKWPvbotsKBoIyfcTEtIzizdiku2uFNSFcabqKuE7OmgwXGAFljrYxjZfa6cMZf3BHSzEcFjp1ktYCMFH7qSNWdemdhJmpWlpNimKbKBI3zV1+RtMGjaNeW4wOP2QcELjKSnDfJlKynRKHjoim40zPXiFRttzPID/7oWB/3EW305H1aexEEKkfr6Mjygd4bWptQ2eyf1xeAE=) demonstrating a possible solution.

```
var path = new Path.Circle({
    radius: 100,
    fillColor: 'blue',
    center: view.center,
    applyMatrix: false
});

path.tween(
    { scaling: 1, fillColor: 'blue' },
    { scaling: 2, fillColor: 'red' },
    2000
);
```